# How does a React app with Flask backend work in production?

Tags: reactjs, flask, deployment

Developing both the backend and frontend side by side results in my React app on `localhost:3000` requesting data from my Flask app on `localhost:5000`. This is okay and it works currently, but I'm unsure how this looks in production, and I'm unsure of the different options. I'll give some information about the use case of the app, because I understand there are multiple ways to set up a React & Flask app.

Initially the website was just a regular Flask app serving HTML, utilizing Jinja, but we want to move into a frontend framework and keep all the data management and ML in Flask. When the app is deployed I'd like the website to only be on `website.com`, and not have to request the backend from a different URL like `api.website.com`. I want to access it from `website.com/api/...`. How do I package everything into one? The backend will only ever be used for this single frontend. There is no mobile app or secondary use case, it's solely for this single application.

Would I still host them on two different servers and just make them think it's the same domain, or can I make the Flask server serve React components and just host the Flask server?  I'd prefer a single server. There's probably a lot that goes into this and I'm okay with being given a link to a tutorial or something, but any guidance or help works. If there is a specific method anyone suggests, I'd would also like a link to some code to see how to set it all up, hence tutorial.

Edit:

When building the React frontend, and wanting a single server, would using something like Next.js not work? Should I use Vite? I'm currently testing all of this with Next, but again am unsure of what exactly to use.

Comment: if you want to use same domain, you 'll have a nginx to route url by prefix /api to server flask and all other path to Font-end server

Answer (score 0):

I found: https://github.com/vercel/examples/tree/main/python/nextjs-flask

Which results in a `next.config.js` file that looks like this:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  rewrites: async () => {
    return [
      {
        source: '/api/:path*',
        destination:
          process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
            ? 'http://127.0.0.1:<flask_server_port>/api/:path*'
            : '/api/',
      },
    ]
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Allowing me to request `localhost:<nextjs_port>/api/<path>`, which will then hit `localhost:<flask_server_port>/api/<path>`.

For example `GET`ing `localhost:5000/api/hello` will return the results from `localhost:8000/api/hello` if my NextJS app is running on port `5000` and my Flask app is running on port `8000`.

```py
@app.route("/api/hello")
def hello_world():
    return jsonify({
        "hello": "world"
    })
```

In order for me to get this to work, the default `npm run dev` command from the example repo didn't work for me. I have to run each server separately from two different terminals, or instead I created a python script that runs them both for me via threads.

```py
from threading import Thread
import subprocess as sp

def flask():
    sp.check_call('npm.cmd run flask-dev')

def next():
    sp.check_call('npm.cmd run next-dev')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target=flask).start()
    Thread(target=next).start()
```

And I run this via `npm run dev` with:

```js
"scripts": {
  "dev": "python run.py",
  "next-dev": "next dev",
  "flask-dev": "flask run",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next start",
  "lint": "next lint"
}
```

in my `package.json`.

And I also found [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/deploying-next-js-flask/) on deploying this type of configuration via Nginx.